# round float values to interval limits / grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got an array of (random) floating point numbers. I want to round each value up to a limit of an arbitrary grid. See the following example:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

# Setup
sample = np.random.normal(loc=20, scale=6, size=10)
intervals = [-np.inf, 10, 12, 15, 18, 21, 25, 30, np.inf]

# Round each interval up
for i in range(len(intervals) - 1):
    sample[np.logical_and(sample > intervals[i], sample <= intervals[i+1])] = intervals[i+1]
```

This results in:

```
[ 30.  18.  18.  15.  30.  10.  inf  18.  25.  21.]
```

How can I avoid the `for` loop? I'm sure there's some way using NumPy's array magic that I don't see right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `intervals` is sorted, you can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
np.array(intervals)[np.searchsorted(intervals, sample)]
# array([ 30.,  18.,  18.,  15.,  30.,  10.,  inf,  18.,  25.,  21.])
```

---

`searchsorted` returns the index of the interval where the element belongs to:

```
np.searchsorted(intervals, sample)
# array([7, 4, 4, 3, 7, 1, 8, 4, 6, 5])
```

The default `side='left'` returns the smallest index of such interval and the result falls into the *left open, right close* scenario.

Comment: Compared this answer with @blue_note's and @pault's answer using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html): it's twice as fast as blue_note's and thrice as fast as pault's. (Sampling of data was taken into the timeit-loop. Results may differ for larger samples / grids).

Comment: Makes sense that this is the fastest because `searchshorted` can short circuit. My solution computes the intervals in a different way, but it requires comparing each value in `sample` to each interval. Would you mind benchmarking `[next(i for i in intervals if i>s) for s in sample]` - it obviously has the for loop, but I am wondering how much the `next()` saves in time. @ascripter

Comment: @pault: `[next(i for i in intervals if i>s) for s in sample]` takes about 4.5 the time compared to `searchsorted`

Answer (score 4):

You can use Pandas `cut()`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.cut(sample, intervals, labels=intervals[1:]).tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
np.array(intervals)[(sample[:,None] > intervals).sum(axis=1)]
#array([30., 18., 18., 15., 30., 10., inf, 18., 25., 21.])
```

Essentially we build a mask that checks to see if the sample is greater than the interval (assumes it's already sorted as in your example). Then we sum along the first axis, which will add up a 1 for every interval that the value is greater than.

The resultant sums are the indices in the `intervals` array.

A non-NumPy solution using a list comprehension (obviously includes the `for` loop, but should be relatively efficient with the generator):

```
new_sample = [next(i for i in intervals if i>s) for s in sample]
#[30, 18, 18, 15, 30, 10, inf, 18, 25, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not run a check but:

```
 from bisect import bisect

 for index, value in enumerate(sample):
     sample[index] = intervals[ bisect( intervals, value)]
```

Comment: OP wanted to avoid the `for` loop

Comment: Indeed but I wanted to share a solution that does not require `numpy`, `bisect` is a built-in.

Answer (score 0):

If `values` is a 1D arrays with your values, you could do something like

```
diff = values < intervals[:, None]
t = np.argmax(diff, axis=0)
new_values = intervals[t]
```