# stepify / grid snap function for numerical array in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rounding

Is there a function in python, numpy, pandas etc. to round a numpy array or pandas Series to certain steps like Godot's [`stepify`](https://docs.godotengine.org/de/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-stepify) does?

> float **stepify** ( float s, float step )
>
> Snaps float value `s` to a given `step`. This can also be used to round a floating point number to an arbitrary number of decimals.
>
> `stepify(100, 32) # Returns 96.0`
>
> `stepify(3.14159, 0.01) # Returns 3.14`

I've asked "[round float values to interval limits / grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502197/round-float-values-to-interval-limits-grid)" already sometime ago where the grid points are non-equally distributed. This one is simpler, and I feel it's simple enough that I shouldn't need to write an own function for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do, for variable `a` and `b`:

```
(a//b)*b
```

As a function:

```
def stepify(a,b):
    return (a//b)*b
```

Using mentioned values as test:

```
print(stepify(100, 32)) # outputs: 96
print(stepify(3.14159, 0.01)) # outputs: 3.14
```

Works for numpy arrays too:

```
print(stepify(np.array([1.2,3.4,4.5]),0.3)) # returns [1.2 3.3 4.5]
```

and for Pandas series:

```
print(stepify(pd.Series([1.2,3.4,4.5]),0.3))

# outputs:
0    1.2
1    3.3
2    4.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Didn't see that. Easy :) Should work for float, array and Series

Comment: Yes :) Added them now.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by `step` size, round, multiply by `step` size. Given `data` is a `numpy.ndarray` or `pandas.Series`:

```
data_stepped = (data / step).round() * step
```

Another approach is given with [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). However you don't provide a step size but *the number of equal-width bins in the range of your data*:

```
pandas.cut(data, bins)
```